# System with arbitrary function of an unknown

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How can I solve the following system
$$ (u_x)^2 - (u_t)^2 = 1 \\
 u_{xx} - u_{tt} = f(u) $$

where $f$ is an arbitrary function of $u$, $u$ and $f$ to be determined.

I don't know any approach, therefore I am very interested about you ideas and grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The first equation looks like the Eikonal equation in $\Bbb R^{1+1}$, it is solved by $u=\sqrt{x-t}$,
you would then plug this into the wave equation to determine $f$.

We see that $u_x=x/u$, $u_t=-t/u$, $u_{xx}=(u-x^2/u)/u^2$ and $u_{tt}=-(u+t^2/u)/u^2$ thus$$u_{xx}-u_{tt}=(u-x^2/u)/u^2+(u+t^2/u)/u^2$$
$$=2u/u^2+(t^2-x^2)/u^3$$ 
$$=2/u-(x-t)(x+t)/((x-t)u)=(2-x-t)/u.$$
Finally notice that